# Creating a BroadcastReceiver Dynamically in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am building an Android app that works by providing information via SMS to users.Users send an SMS to a predetermined number hardcoded in the APP and in turn receive a response.

To achieve this, I am using a broadcast Receiver in my Android Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReciever"> 
        <intent-filter android:priority="2"> 
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

If I create a new class SMSReciever, then when a response is received, I would to somehow send the information back to the activity which the user has open on the screen. Is it possible I can do this in my main activity dynamically so that the app can be made more interactive?

I have learnt about the Context.registerReciever method, but how do I mention the priority for the receiver? If the receiver does not have a higher priority, then the messaging app might stop the broadcast from reaching my app. Has anyone come across a solution for something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the following code to achieve what I was looking for!

```
IntentFilter fp = new IntentFilter();
fp.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
fp.setPriority(18);

//--- when the sms is received ---
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) { 
        //Processing for received broadcast happens here              
    }
}, fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this myself, but I've made a quick search via Android source code.

The priority is parsed and saved into `IntentFilter` (see [code](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java&exact_package=android&q=AndroidManifestIntentFilter_priority&type=cs&l=2602)). So you can create `IntentFilter` and use its [`setPriority()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#setPriority%28int%29) function to set priority of your broadcast receiver.

```
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(...);
 filter.setPriority(receiverPriority);// <-----
 context.registerReceiver(filter, mBroadcastReceiver);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by using a custom intent action like `com.example.intent.VERIFICATION_RECEIVED` and the broadcasting this from `SMSReciever` and then having your `Activity` listen for it with a `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PageFragment.ACTION_LOADING_DONE);
registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(), filter);
```

Using this approach you can keep your SMS handling in `SMSReciever` and your `Activity` doesn't need to care about how to handle a SMS.

Comment: This thought came to my mind and is my approach to solving the issue if nothing else works :)